# How to optimise querying facebook graph API

Tags: django, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-analysis

So we are building a web application that fetches data from FACEBOOK-WORKPLACE. On top of that, we are also building a machine learning algorithm to help in predicting employees that are at risk of employee churn. We're using a predictor called "Reactions Given" in order to get this, we have to

1. Get the user email upon login.
2. Get all the groups associated with the user.
3. Get all the post in each group.
4. Check whether the post was liked by a user.

It is working, but it takes around 2 minutes to run. Any idea how we can optimize this? This is not a problem for analysis purposes but note that we are displaying a summary statistic to the web application, and this can probably result in bad UX.

```
def get_user_groups(self):
    group_list = []
    group = graph.request('%s?fields=groups&limit=999999999999' %self.email_address)
    group = group['groups']['data']

    for i in group:
        group_list.append(i['id'])

    print('User has no groups')
    return group_list


def get_group_feed(self,group_id):
    group_post = graph.request('%s/feed?limit=9999999999' %group_id)

    try:
        group_post = group_post['data']
    except:
        print('Group has no posts')
    return group_post


def get_group_post_list(self):
    group_post_list = []
    for i in (self.get_user_groups()):
        for j in (self.get_group_feed(i)):
            try:
                group_post_list.append(j['id'])
            except:
                print('No id')
    return group_post_list


def get_reaction_given(self):
    for i in self.get_group_post_list():
        print(self.get_reaction_received(i))
```

Comment: Setting limit to a huge number means you are fetching same data again and again, you should better cache old data to your db (or redis). And only fetch around 100 results with pagination till no new results are found. Also profile the given code and tell us which functions are eating up most of the time